Continue CSS animation cycle
I have an animated progress bar where I use the animation-iteration-count CSS property to specify the progress in percentage. So if the progress should be 50% I set animation-iteration-count: 0.5. On page load this works fine and the progress bar animate from 0% to 50%.
But how can I change the progress bar value and continue the CSS animation cycle to a new value? Either a bigger or smaller value. When I change the animation-iteration-count value dynamically with JavaScript the animation jumps to that new value. I want a smooth transition from one value to the next.
If I only wanted to animate the width I could use CSS transitions and have no problems. But since I also want to change the color of the progress bar relative to the progress a CSS animation it much easier.
I have tried experimenting with animation-play-state without luck, but maybe I just didn't do it right. I have also experimented with using @container queries to change the background color of the progress and then use CSS transitions for the width, but that's not doable either.
In the code snippet below you can see my progress bar and click the button to increase the value of the animation-iteration-count property to see that it jumps.


const progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
 progressBar.style.animationIterationCount = "0.75";
})
.progress-bar-container {
    width: 500px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}

.progress-bar {
    height: 10px;
    animation: progressBarAnimation 2s linear forwards;
}


@keyframes progressBarAnimation {
    0% {
        background-color: red;
        width: 0;
    }
    30% {
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 30%;
    }
    60% {
        background-color: green;
        width: 60%;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
<div class="progress-bar-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="animation-iteration-count: 0.5">
    </div>
</div>
<button>Increase progress</button>



Thank you for helping me out!
Regards,
Jeppe

If you click the button, before it has reached the initial 50% mark, then it will smoothly animate to the 75% mark. But if you click it afterwards, then you are modifying an animation, that isn't even in "playing" state any more, but has reached "paused" already. Maybe you could somehow "restart" it, but then you will have to calculate the appropriate negative animation-delay as well, I suppose, so that it doesn't start from the very beginning again. I agree with @0stone0 here - this "hack" is probably rather not the way to go about it.

I already tried restarting the animation play state in combination with a calculation of a negative animation delay, but it will still jump to the next value. So I have trouble with restarting it properly. Feel free to give it a try and see if you can make it work

animation-iteration-count isn't a property used to stop/start the animation.
Setting that through css will restart the animation.
You're probably better of creating a regular progressbar that will use width to animate the grow. Then use a :before element to apply a gradient to your liking.


const progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const current = +progressBar.style.width.slice(0, -1);
    progressBar.style.width = (current === 100)
        ? '25%'
        : (current + 25) + '%';
})
.progress-bar-container {
    width: 500px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
}

.progress-bar {
    height: 10px;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
    mask:linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
}

.progress-bar:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background: linear-gradient(
        90deg, 
        rgba(255,0,0,1) 25%, 
        rgba(247,255,0,1) 50%, 
        rgba(0,255,19,1) 80%, 
        rgba(1,0,255,1) 99%
    );
}
<div class="progress-bar-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 50%"></div>
</div>
<button>Increase progress</button>




Thank you for your comment, but I want to have the same background-color for the progress bar at any given time. So a gradient won't work. If I have a list of progress bars that all are complete/100% I want to see green lines and not rainbow-colored lines.

@JeppeSchaumburgJensen "So a gradient won't work" - who says it has to be a gradient in that direction? :-) Turn it by 90 degrees, and make it bigger than the actual element, by specifying a background-size: auto 100px or something. And then, manipulate the background-position together with the element width ...? (Since the gradient is on the pseudo element, and you can't manipulate the styling of those directly via JS, use a CSS variable on the progress bar element itself. Could even use the same variable for width and background-position-y)

@C3roe that's a good suggestion. But I forgot to specify in my initial post that I also want the background-color to transition from one value to another. It's not possible with linear-gradient as far as I know.
